# xdotool send keystroke even when windows does not have focus

Tags: xdotool, fvwm

I've written the attached script in order to keep my external monitor alive while I'm not typing on it.   I'm using `fvwm`, and have multiple named windows open.    The script successfully types A every second to a named window, but it only works when the window has focus.       How can I modify the script so that it continues to type even when the window doesn't have focus?  Presumably I can use the `behave` option to `xdotool` somehow to do this, but the syntax for `xdotool` with `behave` seems impossibly arcane

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpTITLE=STARTUP0
if [ $# -eq 1 ] ; then
    tmpTITLE=$1
fi
Window=`wmctrl -lp | grep $tmpTITLE | cut -d" " -f 1`
while sleep 1 ; do xdotool key --window $Window A; done
```

Comment: this appears to an XY problem ... perhaps you need to solve the screen blanking problem, instead of solving the workaround that you use .... of course, a solution to your question can be used for other purposes, so it is actually useful for someone

Comment: Obviously I would have fixed X if I could have.   I have an old LG monitor for which the phrase "piece of c**p" would be a huge and undeserved compliment.     So I'm looking for the line of least resistance.     Hence the request.

Comment: Monitors don't get blanked selectively; even if you replaced the "piece of c**p" with a much better monitor it would still likely be blanked. Do you know what program is doing the blanking? If you kill all screensaver processes do you still have the problem? If so, `xset -dpms s off` may do the trick.